# Is my generalization of uniform tightness for random variables mentioned in mathematical literature?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

We consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$,
a sequence $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of random variables on that
space and a sequence $(f_{m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real functions.
The set $\{f_{m}(X_{n})|m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly tight in
$m$ and $n$ (w.r.t. $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$) if
\begin{eqnarray*}
\forall\epsilon>0\exists K>0\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}:\quad\mathbb{P}(|f_{m}(X_{n})|>K)\leq\epsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
I am currently working on the following more general property:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\forall\epsilon>0\exists K>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}:\quad\sup_{n\geq N}\mathbb{P}(|f_{m}(X_{n})|>K)\leq\epsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Does this generalization (or similar properties) exist in
mathematical literature? Would "semiuniform tightness" be an appropriate
name for it?

Comment: The functions $f_m$ are of course measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$.